# aspnetboilerplate email address remove unique validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-core-1.1, aspnetboilerplate

I am using the latest version of aspnetboilerplate, email validation requires for the user entity to be unique by default in the framework, I want to remove this validation to enable multiple user registerions against a single account. Please help me understand how can I disable on this email validation check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough it's not recommended to register different users with same email address (you'll have login problems later) i will try to explain how to remove this check.

The dublicate email check is in AbpUserManager abstract class. So you need to override CreateAsync method.

```
 public override async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(TUser user)
        {

            // Commenting out related lines...
            // var result = await CheckDuplicateUsernameOrEmailAddressAsync(user.Id, user.UserName, user.EmailAddress);
            // if (!result.Succeeded)
            // {
            //   return result;
            // }

            var tenantId = GetCurrentTenantId();
            if (tenantId.HasValue && !user.TenantId.HasValue)
            {
                user.TenantId = tenantId.Value;
            }

            return await base.CreateAsync(user);
        }
```

See the source code > https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero/blob/dev/src/Abp.Zero/Authorization/Users/AbpUserManager.cs#L104